# Azure AD B2C Change enumeration is not supported for requested tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to use a Azure AD Graph [differential query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-differential-query) or Microsoft Graph [delta query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview) to find changes in users within an Azure AD B2C tenant.

For example:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta
GET https://graph.windows.net/{tenantId}/users/?api-version=1.6&deltaLink=
```

Both result in:

`Request_UnsupportedQuery`
`Change enumeration is not supported for requested tenant.`

What is a supported tenant?

Comment: Azure AD Graph [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/25383)

Comment: Microsoft Graph [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4018)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differential query is an enterprise feature rather than a B2C one -- which is why it isn't available in an Azure AD B2C tenant.

Alternatively, you can access [the audit logs in the Azure AD B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-audit-logs) for the CRUD operations on users, using [the Azure AD Reporting API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-audit-logs#accessing-audit-logs-through-the-azure-ad-reporting-api).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that they are not supported in Azure AD B2C, I can reproduce your issue, if I use it with a normal Azure AD tenant, it works fine.

[image]

[image]