# How to Perform Reconciliation Between Azure B2C and Azure SQL Database for 1 Million Customer Records?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a scenario where I'm using Azure B2C with the "xxxxx" tenant to manage user records, and I also have an Azure SQL database that stores user information.

Over time, there may be discrepancies and out-of-sync data between the two sources.

With approximately 1 million customer records to manage,
I'm looking for guidance on how to set up a reconciliation process to detect and rectify these discrepancies.

Comment: I'm not an SQL guru, and the delta functionality is unavailable in B2C, but you may be able to do something from the audit logs. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54788187/azure-ad-b2c-change-enumeration-is-not-supported-for-requested-tenant

Comment: thanks for the reply, so no way to do some reconciliation between azure b2c and SQL Database. I tried ForgeRock, they have something call Remote Connector service to do the reconciliation forgerock and our own database, i am still trying to find a way to do this part...

Comment: I don't know of any utility. Azure AD has MIM that has connectors, but I doubt it works with B2C - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-identity-manager/microsoft-identity-manager-2016

Answer (score 1):

There are no out-of-box tools to manage this sync between SQL Database and Azure AD B2C however there are a few things you could consider.

1. Build an API that updates the database and B2C at the same time. Any user records are updated using this API instead of each app updating the database.
2. When the database is updated publish a service bus message, this in turn is processed by a background worker app and updates B2C.
3. An Azure function using a [SQL Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-azure-sql?tabs=isolated-process%2Cextensionv4&pivots=programming-language-csharp) input binding that updates the record in B2C.
4. Consider not storing the data in two places... This is the single source of truth problem, either store the data in B2C or in SQL, but not both, and link the data boundaries using the B2C Object ID (record matching should only be done on an immutable identifier).

Note, due to the lack of triggers from the Azure AD B2C side these first three above only work from SQL to B2C updates.

You *could* have an API connector (user flows) or REST technical profile (custom policy) that pulls the addition details from SQL negating the need to store it in B2C.

IMO there is an architectural problem here in how data is stored and accessed which is causing your technical issue of keeping things in sync.