# How to limit the number of OTP resends in Azure B2C custom policy?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am currently working on implementing Azure B2C custom policies and I have encountered an issue regarding limiting the number of OTP (One-Time Password) resends.
I followed the instructions provided in the following GitHub repository:

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/mfa-email-or-phone

The problem I am facing is that when I choose email as the OTP method, it allows for an infinite number of resends. This raises concerns regarding security, as there should be a restriction on the number of resends for both email and SMS OTP methods.

[image]

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to enforce a limit on the number of OTP resends in Azure B2C custom policies. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it uses the `PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email"` method, which isn't really an OTP.

Instead, use the proper [OTP mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/one-time-password-technical-profile), which allows you to configure a range of OTP options.

Comment: thanks for the reply.
If I want to use Microsoft to send out OTP, I cannot modify those OTP Options.
If we want to have more OTP Options to control, then i am required to create my SendGrid, Twilio accounts to send out those Custom SMS/ Email.
is that correct?

Comment: see if you could also help me about this question, thanks:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77695468/how-to-perform-reconciliation-between-azure-b2c-and-azure-sql-database-for-1-mil

Comment: Correct - you need to use a third-party provider.